# Job queue in node.js

Tags: php, zend-framework, node.js, queue, job-queue

I'm looking for a job queue manager in node.js which can be invoked by php. This is for a web application which needs to send emails, create pdf files and so on which I'd like to perform asynchronous of the php process.

Example of the process:

1. User requests a php page
2. Php invokes the job queue manager and adds a task
3. Task is executed in node.js asynchronously of php, preferably when it's a bit more quiet
4. Task is to execute a php script

Why this "complex" system?

1. We write all our web-applications in php (Zend Framework)
2. We'd like to start learning node.js
3. We need a asynchronous process (fast response!)
4. The "real" task should be a php script as well, to utilize already written php classes, to have easy access to database connections and be as much DRY as possible

Use cases of this system:

1. User registers himself, system will send welcome email
2. User completes ecommerce order, system will send invoice

In the end, we'd like to use node-cron as well, to perform non-system wide cron tasks (very application specific). Node-cron will invoke the job queue manager, which will subsequently run a php script.

Is there such an application already in node?

Comment: does it have to bridge from php to node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible options is [node-jobs](https://github.com/weepy/node-jobs), which uses Redis.

Comment: Redis is afaik a system wide install. How would we be able to make node-jobs (which I hope can run on a per application base) use redis per application? Or should we make this easy by prefixing all jobs by the application name (probably a reverse TLD)?

Comment: A prefix would probably work: the reverse TLD is a neat trick.

Answer (score 2):

In such a case I would prefer a message queue like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) and client side libraries like [node-amqp](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp) and [php-amqp](http://code.google.com/p/php-amqp/). Then simply send your job from your PHP script in the queue and let nodejs pick up the job from the queue. A big advantage is that it is extensible and it is widely used and tested in the enterprise market.

Comment: Why would you use such a tool for this setup? It seems like it could work, but over-engineered for this goal. Thorough tests and ready for enterprise market are of course advantages, but ease of use and simplicity count as well imho.

Comment: RabbitMQ is well documented, language independent (today it is nodejs the next day python, ruby, java?), active community. Of cause simplicity is always nice, but I choose my technologies also by the activity of the project.